# how to Post data in an array in android using retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

i am facing a problem regarding posting data in an array in android using retrofit 2. i have to post the data of nearly 14 fields in my profile setting activity ...
Like this ...

```
name="basics[first_name] , name="basics[last_name]" , name="basics[phone_number]"
```

i have to send data in this format. i am not understanding how to do it need help.i am not understanding how to make Call of the api in the interface because i have to put data in an array.
Currently i am doing it like this but i know its not right...

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("profile_setting/basic_setting")
    Call<ResponseBody> UpdateBasics(
            @Query("user_id") int user_id ,
            @Field("nickname") String nickname ,
            @Field("first_name") String  first_name ,
            @Field("last_name") String last_name ,
            @Field("phone_number") String phone_number ,
            @Field("fax") String fax
    );
```

Comment: show your url of API. except the domain name.

Comment: https://themographics.com/wordpress/doc_api/wp-json/api/v1/profile_setting/basic_setting    this is the URL for the setting @SushilKumar

Comment: it is a POST Request

Comment: have you checked on POSTMAN ?

Comment: i am not understanding how to post data in array

Comment: i have to pass the data in an array called "basics".

Comment: you want to post it as 14 different variables or in a single object ?

Comment: @Saad Hashmi Make a class with these as fields and make an arraylist of that class. should pass as its mentioned here https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/490

Comment: what error are you getting? check your onFaliure method of retrofit and Logcat and post here

Comment: why not trying to put data in a single Model Class and upload that class as a single object, it would be better approach

Comment: i want these 14 fields in an array of "basics"... thats why i am not understanding how to do that @AliAhmed

Comment: @AliAhmed current apporach isn't wrong

Comment: @AliAhmed can you show me this in the code example?

Comment: @SaadHashmi posted answer please check

Comment: @SushilKumar i'm not saying its wrong. i'm talking about better approach. i believe its easy to post data as single object rather than 14 variables.

Answer (score 2):

Make a class

```
public class Basic {
  public final int user_id;
  public final String nickname;
  ....

  public Basic(int user_id, ...) {

  }
}
```

Then pass list of objects of this class to this interface

```
public interface MyService {
  @POST("/basic")
  Response void sendData(@Body List<Basic> basic);
}
```

Or you can do the same with JSONObject. Just make a list of jsonobjects

```
JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
                    paramObject.put(value_one, "field_one"));
                    paramObject.put(value_second, "field_second"));
```

put the objects in a list

```
list.add(paramObject);
```

then pass to the retrofit

```
public interface MyService {
  @POST("/basic")
  Response void sendJsonObjectData(@Body List<JSONObject> basic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way to send `Json` Object as request parameters using `Retrofit 2`

```
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("profile_setting/basic_setting")
    Call<ResponseBody> UpdateBasics(@Body String body);
```

This is how you would use the above method to send json object

```
try {
                    JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
                    paramObject.put(value_one, "field_one"));
                    paramObject.put(value_second, "field_second"));
                    Call<ResponseBody> userCall = apiInterface.UpdateBasics(paramObject.toString());
                    userCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                            //handle your result here

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                           //handle failure
                        }
                    });
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: hello... what is this value_one , value_second here?  @Quicklearner

Comment: your request params, like name

Comment: first_name, last_name etc

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this was. (posting how i've done that)

```
@POST("Users.json")
Call<UploadData> uploadToken(@Body UploadData uploadData);
```

UploadData.class

```
public class UploadData {

private String DeviceToken, DeviceIMEI;

public UploadData(String deviceToken, String deviceIMEI) {
    DeviceToken = deviceToken;
    DeviceIMEI = deviceIMEI;
}

public String getDeviceToken() {
    return DeviceToken;
}

public String getDeviceIMEI() {
    return DeviceIMEI;
}
}
```

Then in your Activity

```
private void uploadToken() {
     ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
     UploadData uploadToken = new UploadData(deviceToken, imei);
     final Call<UploadData> callUpload = apiInterface.uploadToken(uploadToken);

callUpload.enqueue(new Callback<UploadData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UploadData> call, Response<UploadData> response) {
             if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toasty.success(Main.this, "Token Uploaded !! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
      }

       @Override
       public void onFailure (Call < UploadData > call, Throwable t){
              call.cancel();
              Toasty.error(Main.this, "Error: " + t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

 }
```

Comment: i know how to do it its very simple i am doing it in many other apis ... but i am just confused about name="basics[last_name]"   this basics